# Android GoogleCloudMessaging cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to access `GoogleCloudMessaging`, but I am getting error as `GoogleCloudMessaging cannot be resolved to a type`

I added google-play-services to my project, but still I am getting same error.

My Code:

```
private void check() {
        Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(ctx);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(PushNotificationService.class);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(ctx, PushNotificationService.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 596, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Resources res = ctx.getResources();
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(ctx);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon).setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.icon)).setTicker("New message").setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle("Welcome").setContentText("Hello World!");
        Notification n = builder.build();
        nm.notify(596, n);
    }
```

My project properties Libraries:

[image]

My project properties Order:

[image]

SDK Extras:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved this,

I deleted the google play services from sdk manager and installed again. Imported JAR again and it worked like charm.

Thank you.